# Jquery scroll 1 div other div scroll back

Tags: jquery, css, scroll

i want to build a application interface that allow user to swipe/ scroll the div left, then other div with same class will swipe/ scroll back to original position, but i found that after i scroll the div, the div cannot scroll again, anyone know how to solve this?

here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('.swipe_div').scroll(function(){
          var target = $(this);
          if(target.scrollLeft() >= 1){
            $('.swipe_div').not(target).animate({scrollLeft: 0});
          }
        });
      });
```

fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/ga7eyqvj/

example

http://cdn.andnowuknow.com/thumbnails/3_2.jpg?RSYldA2RrAvIhNLXKpH7YgvaejlDGWjW

Comment: Change `$('.swipe_div').not` to `target.not`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen not working

Comment: do you also want vice-versa?

Comment: @SahilDhir i want something like if i scroll the 1st div, the second div will scroll back, when i scroll second div, the 1st div will scroll back, 
if have multiple scrollable div, when i scroll 1 of it, other div will scrollback to original position
something like IOS delete email function, but i want other swiped div scrollback when i swipe new div, like this http://cdn.andnowuknow.com/thumbnails/3_2.jpg?RSYldA2RrAvIhNLXKpH7YgvaejlDGWjW

Comment: @SahilDhir yes! but can u make it animated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Here is the example code you need.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var scrolling;
  $('.swipe_div').scroll(_.throttle(function() {
    if (!scrolling) {
      scrolling = true;
      $(this).siblings(".swipe_div").not($(this)).animate({
        scrollLeft: 0
      }, 150);
    } else {
      scrolling = false;
    }
  }, 800, {
    leading: true,
    trailing: true
  }));
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.swipe_div {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  background-color: white;
}

.content,
.operation,
.swipe_container {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
}

.swipe_container {
  width: 150%;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  flex-direction: row;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 30pt;
  width: 67%;
  background-color: grey;
}

.operation {
  width: 33%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="swipe_div">
  <div class="swipe_container">
    <div class="content">
      &#x3e;
    </div>
    <div class="operation">

    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="swipe_div">
  <div class="swipe_container">
    <div class="content">
      &#x3e;
    </div>
    <div class="operation">

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="swipe_div">
  <div class="swipe_container">
    <div class="content">
      &#x3e;
    </div>
    <div class="operation">

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your code like :

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    $('.swipe_div').scroll(function(){
      var target = $(this);
      if(target.scrollLeft() >= 1){
        $(this).not(target).animate({scrollLeft: 0});
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: i tried, but no luck, other div not scrolling back to original place

Answer (score 0):

i think you should need like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.swipe_div').scroll(function(){
      var target = $(this);
      if(target.scrollLeft() >= 1){
        $(target).not(target).animate({scrollLeft: 0});
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: @BluYcw can you please explain what you want exactly need, i can't understand properly

Comment: sorry for my poor explanation, here is an example,http://cdn.andnowuknow.com/thumbnails/3_2.jpg?RSYldA2RrAvIhNLXKpH7YgvaejlDGWjW, i want something like if i swipe/ scroll 1st item, the rest of the item will swipe/ scrollback to original position